# How can I limit an OpenFileDialog to only allow the user to select PDF files?

Tags: c#, pdf, openfiledialog

```
ofd.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.*";
```

Why is it that it can still brownse non-pdf files? Is something wrong here?

Comment: I think you understand wrongly the filter variable. It should be `ofd.Filter = "pdf files|*.pdf";` For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Win32_FileDialog_Filter

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is in two parts ([FileDialog.Filter docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

> Label|Extension

Your label is `pdf files (*.pdf)`, but the extension you are filtering by is `*.*`.  Try setting it to `|*.pdf` instead.

In short, the `*.pdf` you have specified is only a descriptive text.  It could be anything.  It is *not* used to filter.